# map direction with two marker, why always show on my system "no point" instead the pathway

Tags: android, json, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

heres my code, pls do help me with this.. I don't know what is the problem with my codes.

when I downloaded this code and modified, my application run smooth, but after a day, the path/direction not appear, and always show no point

mainactivy.java

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
    TextView tvDistanceDuration;
    private GoogleMap map; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        tvDistanceDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_distance_time);

        // Initializing
        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
        //SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        //map = fm.getMap();

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Setting onclick event listener for the map
        map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                // Already two locations
                if (markerPoints.size() > 1) {

                    markerPoints.clear();
                    map.clear();
                }

                // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                markerPoints.add(point);

                // Creating MarkerOptions
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position of the marker
                options.position(point);

                /**
                 * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
                 * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
                 */
                if (markerPoints.size() == 1) {
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                } else if (markerPoints.size() == 2) {
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                }

                // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                map.addMarker(options);

                // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                if (markerPoints.size() >= 2) {
                    LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                }
            }
        });
    }





    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #map} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */



    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;

        return url;
    }

    /**
     * A method to download json data from url
     */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception while", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
     */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            String distance = "";
            String duration = "";

            if (result.size() < 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    if (j == 0) {    // Get distance from the list
                        distance = (String) point.get("distance");
                        continue;
                    } else if (j == 1) { // Get duration from the list
                        duration = (String) point.get("duration");
                        continue;
                    }

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(2);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
            }

            tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:" + distance + ", Duration:" + duration);

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }






    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (map == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (map != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #map} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
```

jsonparser.java

```
package com.example.jhikjake.protomap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /**
     * Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude
     */
    public List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>>();
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;
        JSONObject jDistance = null;
        JSONObject jDuration = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for (int i = 0; i < jRoutes.length(); i++) {
                jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");

                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for (int j = 0; j < jLegs.length(); j++) {

                    /** Getting distance from the json data */
                    jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("text"));

                    /** Getting duration from the json data */
                    jDuration = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDuration = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDuration.put("duration", jDuration.getString("text"));

                    /** Adding distance object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDistance);

                    /** Adding duration object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDuration);

                    jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for (int k = 0; k < jSteps.length(); k++) {
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for (int l = 0; l < list.size(); l++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).latitude));
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).longitude));
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                }
                routes.add(path);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return routes;
    }

    /**
     * Method to decode polyline points
     * Courtesy : jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
     */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }
        return poly;
    }
}
    }
```